# How to use data sets from UCI machine learning repository

Tags: mysql, postgresql, dataset, database, nosql

I am currently working on a project for the applications of differential privacy and I want to experiment with the data that are found in the UCI machine learning repository.

My problem is that I am kind of new using this kind of repositories when it comes to exporting the datasets to a database engine like MySQL, PostgreSQL or even nosql.

So, my question is how could one use any data set from this kind of repositories in a database engine.

I am planning to use this data set
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Communities+and+Crime

Comment: Label your question with the actual database you plan to use, and please include a snapshot of the data you want to use.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to use MySQL database

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I have no experience with this either.*

Since this is tagged [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), I give an answer for that, although [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) works similar.

Since this looks like a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, you could create a table (@relation) with the given columns (@attribute). You must look at each column to see the appropriate type, e.g. numeric might be [`integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) or some `numeric/decimal` type, string can be a [`char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) or `varchar` type.

```
create table crimepredict (
    state int,
    county int,
    community int,
    communityname varchar(255),
    fold int,
    population decimal(3,2),
    ...
)
```

And then you can import the file with the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command

```
copy crimepredict from '/path/to/communities.data' null '?' delimiter ',' quote '' format csv;
```

I don't know, if `quote ''` works. If it doesn't, you must prepare the data file before importing, and wrap the community name with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is a bit old, it is very relevant since it is about the field of differential privacy. The whole paradigm of differential privacy is attaining broader significance in the event of contact tracing and social distancing applications. The paradigm of differential privacy has evolved significantly in these three years.

Adding noise based on the sensitivity of a question is the heart of differential privacy. At the moment, there are two approaches to differential privacy. The noise that protects the data set is either added after the fact by the party that collected the information (known as centralized differential privacy) or the noise is directly built into the act of collecting data (local differential privacy, or random response). In the local version, there’s not even an original “true” database to safe keep — the holder of the information never got it in the first place.

Hence the need to customise the database engine is not always there in the contemporary approaches. Having said that, please let me share an archived project from Uber that has attempted customisation of database engines for differential privacy purposes. Please find it here.

[Uber Tool for Applying Differential Privacy to SQL Queries](https://github.com/uber-archive/sql-differential-privacy)

This repository contains a query analysis and rewriting framework to enforce differential privacy for general-purpose SQL queries. The rewriting engine can automatically transform an input query into an intrinsically private query which embeds a differential privacy mechanism in the query directly; the transformed query enforces differential privacy on its results and can be executed on any standard SQL database. This approach supports many state-of-the-art differential privacy mechanisms; the code includes rewriters based on Elastic Sensitivity and Sample and Aggregate methods.

Recently, there are some interesting tools dynamically enforce differential privacy on data without the use of a custom database or custom query language. [Immuta](https://www.immuta.com/differential-privacy-in-immuta-2-0/) is one of the frontrunners in this regard.